# Enviar formulário sem recarregar a página sendo que são de domínios diferentes

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Estou precisando fazer um método que não recarregue a página e envie os dados para um servidor em outro domínio. Porém estou tendo problemas com o `XMLHttpRequest`. Alguém sabe algum método para fazer isso e conseguir enviar os dados para o *script* PHP que está no outro servidor fora do domínio?

Esse é o método que eu estava tentando fazer:

```
$(function() {

    $('#form1').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var nome = $("#Nome").val();
        var email = $("#Email").val();

        if (nome!='' & email!='') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Insert_blog_tricae2.php",
                contentType: "application/json;         charset=utf-8",
                crossDomain  : "true",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                asynch: true,
                data: {"Nome": nome, "Email":email},
                success: function(retorno){
                    $('#resultado').html(nome+"<br>"+email).fadeIn();
                    $('#Nome').val('');
                    $('#Email').val('');
                    $('#resultado').fadeOut(10000);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#resultado').html('<center>Existem campos incompletos no formul&aacute;rio.<br> Favor preencher todos.</center>').show();
        }
        return false;
    })
})
```

Comment: o código é esse:

Comment: $(function(){
     $('#form1').submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var nome = $("#Nome").val();
      var email = $("#Email").val();

      if (nome!='' & email!='')
      {
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Insert.php",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain  : "true",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        asynch: true,
        data: {"Nome": nome, "Email":email},
        success: function(retorno){
         $('#resultado').html(nome+"<br>"+email).fadeIn();
         $('#Nome').val('');
         $('#Email').val('');

Comment: Qual é o url para onde queres fazer o ajax?

Comment: Você quer o endereço do servidor que eu estou mandando a requisição?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema deve estar no servidor que está recebendo o post.

Você deve usar `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` no servidor que irá receber os dados.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
```

No lugar de `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` você pode fixar o servidor, para impedir que outros domínios comunique com seu servidor que está recebendo sua requisição.

Você pode obter mais informações sobre [Access Control CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (em ingês) no site MDN e no [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) (também em inglês)

Comment: Ok, mas esse código eu coloco no script php que recebe o POST? Não há nenhuma função ajax que possa "burlar" isso?

Comment: Ia esquecendo, obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Blz, funcionou corretamente os códigos que você Leandro Amorim me passou! Valeu

Comment: @RafaeldosSantos se essa resposta resolveu seu problema, considere aceitá-la. Veja mais em: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3117